# For which values of $a$ lie the roots of $z^2+2a(1+i)z+(4+2a^2i)=0$ in the first quadrant of complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given is$$z^2+2a(1+i)z+(4+2a^2i)=0$$ I'm trying to solve it for z by completing the square but I'm stuck. For it to be in the first quadrant both the real and the imaginary part should be positive if I'm not mistaken.

I wrote it as $2ix^2+(2+2i)xz+z^2=-4$ and now I want to square the left side, since the root of the right side is $\pm2i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the equation as$$z^2+2a(1+i)z+(4+2a^2i)=\Big(z+a(1+i)\Big)^2+4=0$$where we have used $\Big((1+i)a\Big)^2=a^2(1+i)^2=2ia^2$ therefore$$z_1=2i-a(1+i)=(2-a)i-a\\z_2=-2i-a(1+i)=(-2-a)i-a$$and they fall in the first quadrant if $$2-a>0\\-a>0\\-2-a>0$$which yield to $$a<2\\a<0\\a<-2$$

> **Conlusion**
>
> For $a<-2$, the roots of $z^2+2a(1+i)z+(4+2a^2i)=0$ reside in the
>   first quadrant.

Comment: Hm, am I maybe misunderstanding the question then. For which values for a is are the roots to "given equation" in the first quadrant of the imaginary numeral system. My thought was that if both the real and the imaginary part are positive it should be in the first quadrant, so I'm trying to find the roots to see what a would give me that

Comment: I understand your answer, I got the same using wolframalpha but what I'm stuck with is how I can re write the left side to $(z+a(1+i))^2$

Comment: Then that makes more sense and yes. Both real and imaginary parts must be positive.

Comment: Actually it comes from $\Big((1+i)a\Big)^2=a^2(1+i)^2=2ia^2$